# Can't get colorscheme to work in VIM in conemu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, vim, conemu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Vim through Bash on Windows. I am using ConEMU as my terminal. I want to change to VIM color scheme to zenburn. In my .vimrc I have the following:

```
set term=xterm
set t_Co=256
colorscheme zenburn 
let &t_AB ="\e[48;5;%dm"
let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"
```

In my .bashrc I have the following line added to that the end:

```
PS1=’\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\033[1;31m\]@\[\033[1;32m\]\h:\[\033[1;35m\]\w\[\033[1;31m\]\$\[\033[0m\]’
```

I have followed everything from [ConEmu help site](http://conemu.github.io/en/VimXterm.html#stack-exchange). I still can't get the colors to work.